# Pygame drawing a rectangle with OOP

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to learn OOP with pygame and make a simple game, I'm loosely following a tutorial, but have tried to modify it to fit my own needs and now it's not working. I'm trying to draw a white rectangle onto a black window, the tutorial draws a blue circle on a black window and when I replace the circle to a rectangle it doesn't work.
My code is sepereated into 2 different files heres the first file:

```
import pygame
import LanderHandler

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)


class MainLoop(object):
    def __init__(self, width=640, height=400):

        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Lander Game")
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height), pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
        self.background = pygame.Surface(self.screen.get_size()).convert()

    def paint(self):
        lander = LanderHandler.Lander()
        lander.blit(self.background)

    def run(self):

        self.paint()
        running = True

        while running:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        running = False

            pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # call with width of window and fps
    MainLoop().run()
```

And my second file:

```
import pygame

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)


class Lander(object):
    def __init__(self, height=10, width=10, color=white, x=320, y=240):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((2 * self.height, 2 * self.width))
        self.color = color

        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, white, (self.height, self.height, self.width, self.width))

    def blit(self, background):
        """blit the Ball on the background"""
        background.blit(self.surface, (self.x, self.y))

    def move(self, change_x, change_y):
        self.change_x = change_x
        self.change_y = change_y

        self.x += self.change_x
        self.y += self.change_y

        if self.x > 300 or self.x < 0:
            self.change_x = -self.change_x
        if self.y > 300 or self.y < 0:
            self.change_y = -self.change_y
```

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be amazing thank you.
P.S. I get no running errors and a black window does pop up, but without a white rectangle.

Comment: `while running:` is main part of code and you don't draw anything in this loop so you don't have anything on screen.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is because you draw rectangle on surface `self.background`

```
lander.blit(self.background)
```

but you never blit `self.background` on `self.screen` which is main buffer and which is send on monitor when you do

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

So you can draw directly on `self.screen`

```
lander.blit(self.screen)
```

or you have to blit `self.background` on `self.screen`

```
lander.blit(self.background)

self.screen.blit(self.background, (0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a function with the name blit because it might get in the way of the actual blit function. Also right here in the second code:

```
pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, white, (self.height, self.height, self.width, self.width))
```

you should use surface

Comment: I don't follow... What do you mean, by using surface?